# Batch File to Check for Directory and copy it over if it does not exist

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a batch file that will check a list of computers for a specific directory and if the directory exist pop-up a message on the screen.

If the directory does not exist then copy it to the remote system.
I have not been able to find any good examples.
The batch file I am working on does not function well at all. It does no tell you when the directory exist, it does not write to the text file and when it goes to copy I am getting invalid path.
This is where I am at now.  Any help would be appreciated as this is my 1st attempt at writing a batch file

```
@echo off    
for /F %%A in (machines.txt) do (    
  if exist "\\%%A\C$\temp\test\" (    
    echo %%A Directory Exits >>exists.txt    
  ) else (    
XCOPY "C:\temp\test\" "\\%%a\c$\Temp\test\" /D /E /C /R /I /K /Y /Q     
)
```

Since the code above was not working I decided to start over and make sure the batch file could find the directory called Test.
When I run the batch file it creates the `missing.txt` file instead of the `exists.txt` file which would indicate that it found the directory. I am not sure why it is not finding the directory or maybe it is but my code is incorrect?

This is what I ran

```
@echo off

for /F %%A in (machines.txt) do (

  if exist "\\%%A\C:\Windows\Test" (

    echo %%A : FOUND >>exists.txt 

  ) else (

    echo %%A : MISSING >>missing.txt

  )

)


Pause
```

Comment: Not sure if `if exist` supports UNC paths, but if it does, you need two leading backslashes...

Comment: Some useful suggestions in here regarding robocopy instead, and trying elevated permissions: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/beebadc6-bcff-4a38-b26a-55fe0d0eb7a5/using-xcopy-with-windows-7-to-copy-from-network-locations?forum=w7itprogeneral

Comment: `pushd` supports UNC paths, it creates a temporary drive and changes to that; this can be used for all the other commands; finally, `popd` restores the previous working directory and descroys the temporary drive...